# Unique module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be an integral domain $M$ be $R$-module. $S^{-1}M$ is localization of $M$ at $S$ as the $S^{-1}R$-module

$i_M:M\rightarrow S^{-1}M$ ; $m\mapsto (m,1)= m/1$

I showed that this is an $R$-module homomorphism.

Let $f: M\rightarrow N$ be an $R$-module homomorphism. Show that there is a unıque $S^{-1}R$-module homomorphism $g: S^{-1}M \rightarrow S^{-1}N$ such that

$i_N \circ f=g \circ i_M$

Uniqueness part is solvable for me, but I can not prove existence part

Comment: Hint: If you already know that $g$ will be unique, what is the image of $\frac{m}{s}$ under $g$ going to be? Use this to define a map $S^{-1}M \rightarrow S^{-1}N$. The important thing is to check that it is well-defined.

Comment: g(m/s)=f(m)/s. But can I say directly g exists

Comment: No, you cannot immediately say so, because expressions of the form $\frac{m}{s}$ are not unique (think of $\frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{6}$), so you have to check that if you have $\frac{m}{s} = \frac{m'}{s'}$ in $S^{-1}M$, then $\frac{f(m)}{s} = \frac{f(m')}{s'}$ in $S^{-1}N$. Then you will have a well-defined map.